# How do I get a google sheet name based on cell value using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a workbook (Google Sheets) with a sheet per user (n users) and a master sheet (1) and in my script I need to get the current sheet name using a constant or variable so it works for every user -> sheet.

I have the sheet name on every user's sheets, on cell B2, using the following code:

```
function sheetName() {return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();}
```

I have a submit button that takes B1, D9 and B6 values for the current user's sheet to update the master sheet, but when trying to use use the sheetname as a variable it doesnt work, most probably because I am missing something minor. The only way it works is to hard code the sheet's name but since it has to be dynamic this doesnt work for me.

One example of many user's sheet name is "user5"

This is part of my code, and ways I tried to do this are commented:

```
    1   var testId = ["B6","A"];
    2   var testStatus = ["D9","Q"];
    3   var cellUpdateDate = ["B1","P"];
    4   function submitStatus() {
    5     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     //var formSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
      //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      //var form_sheet_name = ["B2","M"];
      //var formSS = ss.getSheetByName(form_sheet_name);
      //var formSS = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
      //var formSS = ss.getRange("B2").getValues();
      //var formSS = ss.getRange('B2').getValues();
      //var formSS = ss.getSheetByName(B2);
    6    var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("user5");
    7    var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test Cases");
```

As you can see I tried almost everything. 6 only works when I type "user5", but cant figure it out to make it variable.

Thank you!!!, cheers

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Thank you for your guidance @Cooper. even though I went through the tour before is always hard to know "the right way"...hope is better now...

Comment: Why do you leave all the the commented lines in the code?  And why does the code that remains not do anything? And it's incomplete!

Comment: StackOverFloow has gone to a considerable amount of effort to inform people asking questions what the volunteers here require in term of documenting their questions involving scripts. I believe your question good be greatly improved by a careful reading of this document: [mcve]

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for. Don't you want to retrieve the name of the active sheet? Your function `sheetName()` doesn't do exactly that?

Comment: I need to change line number 6 so is not hardcoded with the name but instead takes the name from the active sheet where you press the submit button

Comment: Well, why not changing `var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("user5");` to `var formSS = ss.getActiveSheet();`? This works for me. Can you please clarify what kind of `submit button` you are using? Is it something like a [clickable image or drawing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  let allSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  let masterSheet = 'Master';
  let sheetNames = allSheets.map(function(sn){
     if (sn.getName() !== masterSheet){
     sn.getRange("B2").setValue(sn.getName())
     }
  })
}
```

This function will post the sheet name in all sheets in 'B2' except the master sheet, is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you Ehab, I just want to be able to get the name of the active sheet instead of hard coding the username which is the sheet name, in this case, user5, which is in B2 as well using the function sheetname